# Second-countability of the Compact Open Topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be polish spaces, is it true that the collection of all continuous functions $C(X,Y)$, of $X$ to $Y$, when equipped with the compact-open topology, is second-countable?

My goal is to prove that the collection of all isometries $I(X,Y)$ of $X$ to $Y$, equipped with the pointwise convergence, is separable. I think that both topologies coincides in $I(X,Y)$, and, if the first assertion is true, since $I(X,Y)$ is metrizable, it would be separable.

Comment: I believe $X$ has to be $\sigma$-compact (so the irrationals to the reals is potentially a counterexample) and maybe locally compact as well.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma in Engelking's General Topology, if $X$ and $Y$ are both second-countable and $X$ is locally compact, then $C(X,Y)$ is second-countable. I'm trying to prove that the collection of all isometrics of $X$ to $Y$, $I(X,Y)$ equipped with the topology of pointwise convergence, is separable. I think that both topologies coincides in $I(X,Y)$ coincides, so I'm trying to go by this path...

Comment: @user34870: Where exactly in Engelking have you found that result? I am looking at exercise 3.4.H on page 165, where there is a similar statement, but about separability, not second-countabilty, and the local-compactness assumption is missing. Engelking himself cites ["On a theorem of Rudin and Klee" by E. Michael](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1961-012-06/S0002-9939-1961-0133108-4/S0002-9939-1961-0133108-4.pdf).

Comment: See the useful answer of @HennoBrandsma to a related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3833204/327486

Comment: This comment below an answer to another question might also be useful, albeit it operates under stronger assumptions than those asked in this question. The stronger assumptions may not all be relevant though: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175146/complexity-of-the-set-of-surjective-continuous-functions#comment403482_175217

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a answer to your first question, but solves the underlying problem. The exercise 3.4.H of Engelking's *General Topology* says something interesting about the $C_p(X,Y)$ (the space $C(X,Y)$ equipped with the pointwise convergence topology) and $C_{co}(X,Y)$ (the space $C(X,Y)$ equipped with the compact-open topology): 
$$\operatorname{nw}(C_p(X,Y))\leq \operatorname{w}(X)\operatorname{w}(Y)\;\text{ and }\operatorname{nw}(C_{co}(X,Y))\leq \operatorname{w}(X)\operatorname{w}(Y)$$
where $\operatorname{nw}(X)$ is the *network weight* of $X$ (see [this](https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/11/14/spaces-with-countable-network/))
Once you prove that $\operatorname{nw}(C_p(X,Y))\leq \operatorname{w}(X)\operatorname{w}(Y)$, it's easy to see that, for every subspace $S$ of $C_p(X,Y)$, $\operatorname{d}(S)\leq \operatorname{nw}(S)\leq\operatorname{nw}(X)$. So, if $X$ and $Y$ are both second-countable spaces, then $C_p(X,Y)$ and $C_{co}(X,Y)$ are both hereditarily separable.

Answer (score 1):

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be polish spaces, is it true that the collection of all continuous functions $C(X,Y)$, of $X$ to $Y$, when equipped with the compact-open topology, is second-countable?

Not necessarily.

Moreover, if $X$ is not $\sigma$-compact zero-dimensional space and $|Y|>1$ then $C(X,Y)$ is even not first countable. For instance, if $X=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R$ endowed with the standard topology; it is not $\sigma$-compact by Baire Theorem, beacuse each compact of the space $X$ is nowhere dense.

Indeed, let $f_0: X\to Y$ be an arbitrary constant map such that $f_0(x)=y_0$ for all $x\in X$. Assume that the space $C(X,Y)$ has a countable base at the point $f_0$.

It is easy to show that it has a countable subbase  $$\{M(K_n, U_n): K_n\text{ is a compact subset of $X$ and $U_n$ is open in }Y\} \,,$$ where $M(K,U)= \{f\in C(X,Y): f(K)\subset U\}$.

Since the space $X$ is not $\sigma$-compact, there exists a point $x_0\in X\setminus\bigcup K_n$.

Pick from $Y$ an arbitrary point $y_1$ distinct from $y_0$. We claim that there exist no finite family $\mathcal F$ of the form $\{ M(K_n, U_n):n\in F\}$ such that $f_0\in\bigcap\mathcal F\subset M(\{x_0\}, Y\setminus\{y_1\})$.

Indeed, assume the converse. Put $K=\bigcup\{K_n: n\in F\}$.

Since the set $K$ is compact, it is closed in $X$. Since the space $X$ is zero-dimensional, there exists a disjoint from $K$ closed and open neighborhood $V$ of the point $x_0$.

Define a (continuous) map $f:X\to Y$ by putting $f(x)=y_0$, if $x\in X\setminus V$ and $f(x)=y_1$, if $x\in V$. Then $f\in \bigcap\mathcal F\setminus  M(\{x_0\}, Y\setminus\{y_1\} )$ , a contradiction.

We can similarly prove that a case when $X$ is Tychonoff and not $\sigma$-compact and $Y=[0,1]$ is also a counterexample.

Comment: To clarify, is this saying that "A necessary condition for the claim to be true is if $X$ is a _$\sigma$-compact_ Polish space" (as opposed to an arbitrary Polish space, like in the statement of the question)? For example I don't really understand where "zero-dimensionality" comes in (afaiu any zero-dimensional manifold has the discrete topology -- are you referring to discrete topological spaces when saying "zero-dimensional")?

Comment: @Chill2Macht This says that if the claim is true and $|Y|>1$ and $X$ is zero-dimensional then $X$ is $\sigma$-compact. Zero-dimensionality of $X$ is used when we pick the disjoint from $K$ closed and open neighborhood $V$ of the point $x_0$. A Polish zero-dimensional space $X$ can be a non-manifold, it can even be non-locally compact, for instance, the above example $X=\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$.

Comment: To clarify, when we're talking about "zero-dimensional", we mean in the (equivalent) senses of that term as defined for Polish spaces? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-dimensional_space Sorry for the dumb questions -- I had never heard the term used outside of the context of manifolds before.