# Second countability of compact open topology

Tags: general-topology, second-countable

Let $X, Y$ be topological spaces and $C(X,Y)$ the set of continuous functions with the compact open topology defined as having the subbasis consisting of all subsets $C(K, U)$ of functions $f$ for which $f(K) \subseteq U$, where $K$ is compact and $U$ is open. My question has two aspects:

1. I am particularly interested in the case where $X,Y$ are both second countable, locally euclidian and Hausdorff. Is then $C(X,Y)$ second countable, or at least first countable?
2. Are there any known weaker sufficient conditions on $X$ and $Y$ such that $C(X,Y)$ is second countable or at least first countable?

Regarding 1., I'm thinking $X$ being locally euclidian is useful because given a basis, the sets in it which are relatively compact form a subbasis. But before I can get to that, I am already stuck at the fact that, if $U$ is open in $Y$, $\left\{ U_i \right\}$ is a countable basis and $U=\cup_{i \in I_U} U_i$, one only has $\cup_{i \in I_U} C(K, U_i) \subseteq C(K, U)$, but not necessarily equality.

Comment: This comment on an answer to a related question may be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175146/complexity-of-the-set-of-surjective-continuous-functions#comment403482_175217 I believe locally Euclidean + Hausdorff + second countable should imply separable and completely metrizable, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Locally Euclidean as such is irrelevant. But it is well-known that if $X$ and $Y$ are second countable Hausdorff and $X$ is locally compact (which does follow from locally Euclidean), then $C(X,Y)$ is second countable.

If $C(X,Y)$ is second countable, $Y$ also is (as the set of constant functions is a homeomorphic copy of $Y$ in it, and second countability is hereditary). For a locally compact $X$ and $Y=\Bbb R$ Thm 4.8 in [this survey paper](https://rendiconti.dmi.units.it/volumi/39/26.pdf) shows that $C(X,Y)$ second countable implies $X$ second countable too. I think this will stay true for arbitrary second countable metrisable $Y$.

As to first countability, this is more complicated IIRC. McCoy and Ntantu have written papers on the problem of when $C(X,Y)$ is first countable. The linked paper I gave has some references to get you started on that if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you! Could you also point towards a place where I could find the proof that if $X$ and $Y$ are second countable and $X$ locally compact , then $C(X,Y)$ is second countable? I've been googling quite a bit to no avail.

Comment: Never mind, it is in the paper you referenced, maybe with details to be filled in by Ntantu's doctoral thesis.

Comment: @rosecabbagedragon Also 3.4.16 in Engelking (*General Topology* 2nd ed. 1989) proves it. It probably is in Kelley too, or Wilansky.